# Trying to remove checkboxes from specific table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I'm trying to add checkboxes to a table using Javascript and then remove them from totals columns (that have class "kn-table-totals"). However, my code removes **all** of the checkboxes. I have a table that displays some data and totals the values at the bottom. I'd like the checkboxes at the start of each data set but not the in the totals columns. See the fiddle below. Heres my code:

```
$('#' + view.key + '.kn-table tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<td><input type="checkbox"></td>');
});
   $('#' + view.key + '.kn-table tbody tr.kn-table-totals td input').each(function() {
    $(this).remove()
}
```

Here's one of the checkboxes I'm trying to target:

```
<tr class="kn-table-totals">
<td style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); border-top: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218); text-align: right;">
<strong>Totals - 
<input type="checkbox">
</strong>
</td>
```

The full code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/rainybird/50wya2k7/1/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Kindly add the code for the HTML as well.

Comment: Okay, I've added the HTML :)

Comment: I mean add the full HTML for the table.

Comment: It's too many characters?

Comment: Then add it to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share the link with us

Comment: Okay, I've made a fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check for unique identifier eg. `checkbox value` or `id`.

Example:

Using value `<input type="checkbox" value="value1">`

```
$(`#${view.key}.kn-table tbody tr.kn-table-totals td input[value='value1']`).remove();
```

Using id `<input type="checkbox" id="uniqueId">`

```
$(`#${view.key}.kn-table tbody tr.kn-table-totals td input#uniqueId`).remove();
```

Comment: Do I need to use value/id when adding the checkboxes and when removing those I don't need? That's what I've done but I get the same result.

Comment: What you have done is deleting all the items. What i gave you as an example is deleting only one item.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'm trying to remove them from all of the totals columns without having to change the code each time I'd like to add a new totals column.

Comment: You confused me on that last comment. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I've padded out my question a bit and added a fiddle, hopefully it should make more sense now.

Comment: I see there is a logical problem. So for you to be able to manipulate totals easier you will need to somehow group the affected rows and use for example `var columnTotal = 0; $('.totalSection [data-field-key="field_93"]').each(function() {columnTotal += $(this).find('span').val(); });` and you will make this a generic function when the table is manipulated this functions will run to update totals.

Answer (score 0):

> However, my code removes all of the checkboxes

Nope nothing is removed. The checkboxes will never added. This is because you have a typo in your code. The `.each()` closing bracket `)` is missing.

Change

```
$('#' + view.key + '.kn-table tbody tr.kn-table-totals td input').each(function() {
    $(this).remove()
}
```

To this instead

```
$('#' + view.key + '.kn-table tbody tr.kn-table-totals td input').each(function() {
    $(this).remove()
})
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for finding this, the code still doesn't remove the checkboxes though

Comment: _"the code still doesn't remove the checkboxes though"_ You mean it's now working?

Comment: No, it's not working. The first part of the code adds the checkboxes but the second fails to remove the ones from the totals columns.